# AWS Step Functions execution error: The resource provided in the resource ARN is not supported

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have a project that uses AWS services. In it there is a state function defined in this way:

```
{
  "Comment": "WESII internal pipeline",
  "StartAt": "FileUploadingWatcher",
  "States": {
    "FileUploadingWatcher": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:state:::lambda:invoke.waitForTaskToken",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": "WesiiPipelines-dev-FileUploading",
        "Payload": {
          "token.$": "$$.Task.Token",
          "metadata.$": "$.metadata"
        }
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.uploaded_files",
      "Next": "ProcessingWorker"
    },
    "ProcessingWorker": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:eu-west-1:777224273129:activity:ProcessingWorker-dev",
      "ResultPath": "$.processing_location",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

In the last week every execution of the step-functions fails giving this error:

```
An error occurred while executing the state 'FileUploadingWatcher' (entered at the event id #2). The resource provided in the resource ARN is not supported.
```

[image]

I haven't done any deploy in a year, so I have not changed any of the aws resources used by the project. What could be causing this error?

Comment: `arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke.waitForTaskToken` != `arn:aws:state:::lambda:invoke.waitForTaskToken` - `states` vs. `state`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-lambda.html

Comment: `arn:aws:state:::lambda:invoke.waitForTaskToken` has always worked until a week ago. Has something been updated on the AWS side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this issue due to a typo in the arn containing a missing `s`. The correct resource name you require is:

```
arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke.waitForTaskToken
```

You did mention this has not changed in over a year, are there confirmed execution logs showing this state being entered and exited without failure?

Comment: I could show you hundreds of executions of this state function all without errors, pretty much all of the last year, except the last week so out of the blue. However your answer solved my problem.